# SOQL Dynamic Query building using Map.get(List)

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql

I have a doubt.
Suppose I want to query on Account object filtering based on a given list of IDs.
Below snippet works fine when I have a list of Ids.

```
List<String> accountIds = new List<String> {'1','2'};
String query = ' Select ID, Name From Account Where ID in :accountIds';
Database.query(query);
```

But when I use a Map with List as Values, it gives me an exception.

```
Map<String, List<String>> acntIdMap = new Map<String, List<String>>{'ids' => accountIds};
String key = 'ids';
query = ' Select ID, Name From Account Where ID in :acntIdMap.get(key)';
Database.query(query);
```

Exception thrown is 
System.QueryException: unexpected token: '('.

Is there any way to use the list coming from a map in SOQL query.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
Map<String, List<String>> acntIdMap = new Map<String, List<String>>{'ids' => accountIds};
String key = 'ids';
List<String> keys = acntIdMap.get(key);
query = ' Select ID, Name From Account Where ID in :keys';
Database.query(query);
```

as dynamic SOQL only supports [simple bind variables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm).

Comment: Thanks! Your answer will work fine if I have one filter. Say I have dynamic no of filters coming as follows. String query = 'select id ,name from account where ' ; Map<String, String> fieldNameToTypeMap and Map<String, List<Object>> fieldToDataMap.  I want to iterate the fieldToDataMap and dynamically build query with all filters sent.  Somewhat like below  for(String field : fieldNameToTypeMap){  query = query + ' in :fieldToDataMap.get(field)'; }

Comment: Will all filters be on IDs only ?

Comment: No, It can be on any fields available in Account Object. Suppose the request comes to add Id, Name, Source fields as filters with their lists of values each. I want to iterate across all fields and append their data to the query for each filter field